# Batch file to rename files within a folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename

I require a batch file to add a prefix / rename each file within a folder. I have 125 folders with varying file types and lengths, and I would just like to copy the batch file into each folder, specify the ID number to be added to the front of each file. I have the following code which does not seem to work.

```
@echo off
set /p %id% = "Set ID Number: "
for %a in (*.*) do ren %a "%id - %a"
```

Comment: In batch files you need to double the `%` signs in front of `for` variable, so `for %a in (*.*) do ...` works only when entered directly into command prompt, whereas you need to state `for %%a in (*.*) do ...` in batch files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you've gotten slightly wrong, try this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set/P "id=Set ID Number: "
For %%A In (*) Do Ren "%%A" "%id% - %%A"
```